# How to write generic version of variadic template class that calculates sum of integers

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I came across the following code (below) on this site

https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-insights-variadic-templates

But this declaration/definition works only with integers and I want to write a version that works with other types like float, double, std::strings and user defined types that overloads "+" operator. However I am struggling to write one.

Please note that the mentioned site has variadic function template based solution that works with different datatypes including floating point types(not tried with user defined types yet). I am looking for a variadic template class based solution. This is purely for learning purpose.

Can someone please help me to get this right?

```
#include<iostream>

template<int...>
struct add;

template<>
struct add<>
{
  static constexpr int value = 0;
};

template<int i, int... tail>
struct add<i, tail...>
{
  static constexpr int value = i + add<tail...>::value;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << add<1,2,3,4>::value;
}
```

I wrote this but got stuck

```
template<typename ...>
struct add;

template<typename T, typename... args>
struct add<T, args...>
{
    static constexpr T value = ??//T();//what to write here?
};
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Takes the orginal example and replace `int` by `auto`. You can simplify the code using fold expressions.

Comment: C++11, C++14 or C++17?

Comment: @NeutronStar one up-vote for the good question. I posted an answer. Please take a look and please feel free to ask if further explanation is needed. I also appreciate up-votes/acceptance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also **possible** to do so for **non integer** types with some modification!

Templates non-type, non-template parameters should be of integer types or of reference/pointer with a linkage or some limited more possibilities. One can read the full list here [Template parameters and template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter).

Since floating types can not appear as templates non-type, non-template parameters/arguments, the best next option is to take them by reference.

So the `struct` becomes like:

```
template<auto& ...>
struct add{
    static constexpr auto value = 0;
};
template<auto& first, auto& ... others>
struct add<first, others...>{
    static constexpr auto value = first + add<others ...>::value;
};
```

Values should be stored as constants (with a linkage) first, so before `main()`:

```
const auto v1 = 12; //int
const auto v2 = 54L; //long
const auto v3 = 3.25242; //double
const auto v4 = 75.7256L; //long double
```

Then they can be used any where:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << add<v1, v2, v3, v4>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Possible output:

```
144.978
```

It works not only with (mixed) integer types and (mixed) floating types but also any custom type provided that the custom types satisfy specific properties including having `constexpr` constructors  and `operator +`. It also has to have some sort of type conversion operator or other means to achieve similar functionality.
For example this type can be used:

```
class custom_type{
    const float v;
    //this one works too but the first is better for the purpose.
    //float v;
public:
    template<typename T>
    constexpr custom_type(T v_):v(v_){}
    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto operator +(T o)const{
        return o + 7345 + v ;
    }
    //this one works but the next one is  better for the purpose.
    //operator auto()const{
    //this one works too but the next one is more clear.
    //constexpr operator auto()const{
    template<typename T>
    constexpr operator T()const{
        return v;
    }
};
```

Putting it all together:

```
template<auto& ...>
struct add{
    static constexpr auto value = 0;
};
template<auto& first, auto& ... others>
struct add<first, others...>{
    static constexpr auto value = first + add<others ...>::value;
};

class custom_type{
    const float v;
public:
    template<typename T>
    constexpr custom_type(T v_):v(v_){}
    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto operator +(T o)const{
        return o + 7345 + v ;
    }
    template<typename T>
    constexpr operator T()const{
        return v;
    }
};

const auto v1 = 12; //int
const auto v2 = 54L; //long
const auto v3 = 3.25242; //double
const auto v4 = 75.7256L; //long double
const custom_type v5 = 34.234; //custom_type

#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << add<v1, v2, v3, v4, v5>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Possible output:

```
7524.21
```

Please note the `struct add` for C++ versions lower than 17 can only take arguments of a single type and  for the type `double` would be like:

```
template<const double& ...>
struct add{
    static constexpr double value = 0;
};
template<const double& first, const double& ... others>
struct add<first, others...>{
    static constexpr double value = first + add<others ...>::value;
};
```

And constants:

```
const double v1 = 12;
const double v2 = 54L;
const double v3 = 3.25242;
const double v4 = 75.7256l;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer. I was looking for something this only.
I really learned something new here specially how to pass non-type template parameter by const reference. And also thank you for showing the example with custom type. Without knowing that I would need a constexpr constructor, I would have surely struggled with it. Let me play more with your code and i'll get back to you if I have more queries.

Comment: @NeutronStar (as I said before) Thank you for your question friend!  And let me tell you that It also made some questions (regarding [Storage duration and linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration))for me that I think I am going to ask myself! So again thank you for your question, your up-vote  and accepting my answer!

Answer (score 2):

What about something as follows ?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, T...>
struct add
{ static constexpr T value = 0; };

template <typename T, T head, T ... tail>
struct add<T, head, tail...>
{ static constexpr T value = head + add<T, tail...>::value; };

int main()
 {
    std::cout << add<int, 1, 2, 3, 4>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << add<long, 10l, 20l, 30l, 40l>::value << std::endl;
 }
```

Or, maybe better, inheriting from `std::integral_constant`

```
template <typename T, T...>
struct add : public std::integral_constant<T, T{0}>
{ };

template <typename T, T head, T ... tail>
struct add<T, head, tail...>
   : public std::integral_constant<T, head + add<T, tail...>::value>
{ };
```

If you can use C++17, you don't need recursion anymore but you can use template folding.

```
template <typename T, T... Is>
struct add : public std::integral_constant<T, (... + Is)>
 { };
```

C++17 also offer you the opportunity of get rid of the `typename T` type argument, using `auto` for the values.

The problem become: which type is the `value` considering that the template values are, potentially, of different types?

I suppose that `std::common_type` can be the solution for this question, so

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <auto ... Is>
struct add :
   public std::integral_constant<std::common_type_t<decltype(Is)...>,
                                 (... + Is)>
 { };

int main()
 {
    std::cout << add<1, 2, 3, 4>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << add<10l, 20l, 30l, 40l>::value << std::endl;
 }
```

or, maybe, simply using `decltype((... + Is))`

```
template <auto ... Is>
struct add :
   public std::integral_constant<decltype((... + Is)), (... + Is)>
 { };
```

Off topic: the original `add` can be simplified a little as follows

```
template <int...>
struct add
 { static constexpr int value = 0; };

template <int i, int... tail>
struct add<i, tail...>
 { static constexpr int value = i + add<tail...>::value; };
```

I mean: not two specializations but a main version (that is the ground case for recursion) and a single specialization (the recursion case).

Or, at least, I see this as a little simplification.

Comment: Thank you for showing me various ways of doing it. But I want it to work with floating point types, strings and user defined types.

I tried with double and std::string and got the error "non-type template parameter cannot be of type double or basic_string<char....."


Please see I have edited my question to add more clarity on what I am looking for.

Comment: @NeutronStar - Sorry: I didn't understand that the problem was the use with types as floating or classes. Unfortunately a floating point value (but also a `std::string` value) can't be a template parameter. The best I can imagine is insert a floating point as a `static constexpr` value inside a struct of some type and pass that struct (the type) as template parameter. But, as you can imagine, is a completely different type of solutions and is a lot less elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you don't want to write a simple fold-expression for whatever reason.

We need an actual *value* of type `T` as a (non-type) template argument.  The easiest way to get this is to use `auto` as its type:

```
template<auto ...>
struct add;

template<auto t>
struct add<t>
{
    static constexpr auto value = t;
};

template<auto t, auto... args>
struct add<t, args...>
{
    static constexpr auto value = t + add<args...>::value;
};
```

Demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::cout << add<1, 2, 3>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << add<1u, 2, -4>::value << '\n';
}
```